# Let $\alpha := \liminf_{x \to a} f(x)$. Is there a net $(x_t) \subset X$ such that $x_t \to a$ and $f(x_t) \to \alpha$?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf, nets

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f:X \to \mathbb R$. Let $a \in X$ and $\mathcal N_a$ be the set of all neighborhoods of $a$. Let
$$
\alpha := \liminf_{x \to a} f(x) := \sup _{V \in \mathcal N_a} \inf _{x \in V} f(x).
$$

If $(x_d) \subset X$ is a net such that $x_d \to a$ and $f(x_d) \to \beta$, then I [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4496527/liminf-is-the-smallest-cluster-point-in-the-setting-of-net-convergence) that $\beta \ge \alpha$.

**My question:** Is there a net $(x_t) \subset X$ such that $x_t \to a$ and $f(x_t) \to \alpha$?

---

**Update:** It seems I have found the required construction.

For each $(V, n) \in \mathcal N_a \times \mathbb N$, by axiom of choice, we pick $x_{V, n}$ such that
$$
f(x_{V,n}) < \inf _{x \in V} f(x) + \frac{1}{n}.
$$

We define a partial order $\le$ on $\mathcal N_a \times \mathbb N$ by
$$
(V_1, n_1) \le (V_2, n_2) \iff (V_1 \supset V_2) \wedge (n_1 \le n_2).  
$$

Then $(\mathcal N_a \times \mathbb N, \le)$ is a directed set. It's clear that $\{f(x_{V,n}) \mid (V, n) \in \mathcal N_a \times \mathbb N\}$ is a net. Let's prove that $f(x_{V,n}) \to \alpha$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Then $(\alpha - \varepsilon, \alpha + \varepsilon)$ is a neighborhood of $\alpha$. There is $V'$ such that
$$
\alpha - \varepsilon < \inf _{x \in V'} f(x) < \alpha + \varepsilon.
$$

We pick $n'$ such that $\dfrac{1}{n'} < \varepsilon$. Then
$$
\alpha - \varepsilon < \inf _{x \in V'} f(x) \le \inf _{x \in V} f(x) \le f(x_{V,n}) < \inf _{x \in V} f(x) + \varepsilon \le \alpha +\varepsilon \quad \forall (V, n) \ge (V', n')
$$

This means $f(x_{V,n}) \in (\alpha - \varepsilon, \alpha + \varepsilon)$ for all $(V, n) \ge (V', n')$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Remember, every sequence is a net; by the defintion of $\liminf$ you have a convergent sequence $x_t\rightarrow a$ such that $f(x_t)\rightarrow \alpha.$

Comment: @PCeltide ... No, if $X$ is not first-countable, there may be no **sequence** with $x_n \to a$.

Comment: What happens when you to to prove it?  Perhaps build your directed set from $\mathcal N_a$ .

Comment: @GEdgar I have found a construction for such a net. Could you have a check on my update?

Comment: Good.  You should say $x_{V, n} \in V$ .

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you so much for your help!